# Web Design: Table Unequal Columns

Tags: wordpress, web

I have a quick question with designing the "yearly subscription" pricing table here - http://iknowfirst.com/4637-2/

As you can see,the columns are not all equal in height, and I am not sure how to go about fixing this.  All I did was duplicate the tables used in the "monthly subscription" tab and change some of the information.  Anyone have any solutions for fixing this?

Your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You've got a couple of options. On the cells that are longer, you'll notice they have extra lines of text.

1) Just add

```
<br>
```

to add blank lines to the other cells.

2) Assign CSS classes to each row of cells, and set a min-height property.

Personally, I'd go with #1.